# Simulation of timeseries in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, simulation

I need to make a simulation in R of the following function:

```
y[t] = 4 + (9*x[t-1])*y[y-1]+r[t]
```

I also need to make a 3D plot. I'm new to R, and I therefore find it extremely difficult and hope that someone in here can help me.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
library(rgl)
n <- 3000
x <- runif(n,-1,1)
r <- rnorm(n)
y <- rep(NA,n)
y[1] <- r[1]
for(t in 2:n){
y[t] <- 4 + (9*x[t-1])*y[t-1]+r[t]
}
D <- data.frame(y=y[-1], x1=x[-n],y1=y[-n])
open3d()
points3d(D$x1, D$y1, D$y, size=3, col="red")
aspect3d()
axes3d()
```

But I don't know if the simulation is done correctly, and nothing is shown when I plot the data points. I use the

Comment: Sorry, it is rgl, the spelling was incorrect.

Comment: Your results seem to have a lot of infinite values. Try plotting something simple like `plot3d(runif(5), runif(5), runif(5))` and go from there. Post back here if you have success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `y <- 4 + 9*x[t-1])*y[t-1]` its rise like geometric progression `10^t` ("**9**" coefficient) ...
The problem in "9" and "4" coefficients.
you would have "**Inf**" of "**-Inf**" most y. The rest 'y' would be huge...

Comment: try  y[t] <- 1 + (1.01*x[t-1])*y[t-1]+r[t]

Answer (score 0):

Your simulation works fine, it's just that the values get too large too quickly. I've removed the infinite values and logged the large ones:

```
D <- D[!is.infinite(D$y) & !is.infinite(D$y1),]
D$y <- log(D$y)
D$y1 <- log(D$y1)
plot3d(D)
```

The above code successfully produces a 3D plot.